# Fixed element is covered with the lower element on IOS devices while scrolling

Tags: html, ios

Recently i have been developing web H5 app, and came across a technical problem. 
The fixed element 'Header' is covered by lower element on IOS devices when I drag down the lower element, however on the Android devices, it is ok;

Here is the captured picture:
[Here is the failed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIVpp.jpg)

Following is my code:

```
.hony-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: rem(88);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color:
```

I have raise the z-index up to 9999, it does not work at all; i guess it may be IOS compatibility issue. 
Anyone could help me out, really thanks!

Comment: Fixed the problem: i set the "overflow: hidden" & "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;" for 'body';
Refer to https://www.cnblogs.com/xiahj/p/8036419.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **em** (local sizing) over **rem** (Global sizing).

Also, Could you include a snippet so we can live test?